# Pdf.js add thumbnail view

Tags: javascript, pdf, thumbnails, pdf.js, viewer

I was able to display the pdf pages and navigate through them. The [helloworld](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/tree/master/examples/helloworld) example guided me.

But now I am struggling to add a thumbnails view. Is there a function or a class that I should extend to generate the view. Or is the only way to create a thumbnails view is by looping through the pdf pages and creating images for each.

Comment: The demo viewer is looping through the pages to generate thumbs. If you want to generate thumbs for all pages you will need to wait since parsing of pdf data is a slow task (even in native viewers)

Comment: What do you want to do exactly ? Create a thumbnail for the first page, as a preview of the pdf file ? Or create a thumbnail for each page and display them all ?

Comment: Thumbnails for each page and display them all.